# How to establish parent child relationship my sql

Tags: mysql

pls anyone help to me add foreign key(parent child relation ship)
i have two table coursemaster and course subject  in coursemasteri have 2 column course code and course nameand in course subject i have 2 column course code and subject code now my aim is if i  or update on coursemaster table ie(course code) it should reflect in course subject and if i delete in coursemaster it should not delete unless deleted in coursesubject.

my coursemaster table structure

```
Field   Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action
    id  int(11)         No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT   Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index  Fulltext
    course_code varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       No           Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index  Fulltext
    course_name varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       Yes NULL         Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index  Fulltext
```

course subject

```
Field   Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action
    id  int(11)         No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT   Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index  Fulltext
    course_code varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       Yes NULL         Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index  Fulltext
    subject_code    varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       Yes NULL         Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index  Fulltext
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE`**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `coursemaster` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `course_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `course_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index-1` (`course_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `coursemaster` (`id`, `course_code`, `course_name`) VALUES
    (1, '001', 'French'),
    (2, '009', 'English');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `course_subject` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ` course_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  ` subject_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_1_idx` (` course_code`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_1` FOREIGN KEY (` course_code`) REFERENCES `coursemaster` (`course_code`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `course_subject` (`id`, ` course_code`, ` subject_code`) VALUES
    (1, '009', '4554');
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.but i dont want to delete course code in coursemaster if it present in coursesubject table.